# rails Foo::Engine.config.something is not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an initializer for an engine named `Foo` like so:

```
# config/initializer/foo.rb
class Foo::Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  config.bar = 'baz'
end
```

But it behaves in unexpected ways:

```
Foo::Engine.config.bar # => 'baz' # expected
defined?(Foo::Engine.config.bar) # => nil, why?
```

Why is `defined?` nil?

Also, when I do `Foo::Engine.config.inspect` many things show up but `bar` is nowhere to be found. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `#bar` is not a real method on `Rails::Engine::config` but is implemented via `#method_missing` in [`Rails::Railtie::Configuration`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb). If it were a real method (implemented with `def bar`) `defined?` would return `"method"`.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'bar'
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    if name == :baz
      'baz'
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar           # => "bar"
defined?(f.bar) # => "method"
f.baz           # => "baz"
defined?(f.baz) # => nil
```

And to address the second part of your question, `#inspect` does not include `bar` is because the configuration options are stored in the `@@options` class variable, not in an instance variable where `#inspect` normally looks:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
  if name.to_s =~ /=$/
    @@options[$`.to_sym] = args.first
  elsif @@options.key?(name)
    @@options[name]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Expressions @ Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#definedandorandnot),

The `defined?` operator returns `nil` if its argument (which can be an arbitrary expression) is not defined, otherwise it returns a description of that argument.

```
defined? 1 → "expression"
defined? dummy → nil
defined? printf → "method"
defined? String → "constant"
defined? $& → nil
defined? $_ → "global-variable"
defined? Math::PI → "constant"
defined? ( c,d = 1,2 ) → "assignment"
defined? 42.abs → "method"
```

So for classes:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > defined? Person

 => nil

ruby-1.9.2-p180 > class Person

ruby-1.9.2-p180 ?>  end

 => nil

ruby-1.9.2-p180 > defined? Person

 => "constant"
```

For methods:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > def cool

ruby-1.9.2-p180 ?>  puts "clear"

ruby-1.9.2-p180 ?>  end

 => nil

ruby-1.9.2-p180 > defined? cool

 => "method"
```

**In your case**,

`defined?(options)` is calling the options method and passing the result to `defined?`.

Thanks to @Stuart, as mentioned that its not a real method but its implemented by [method_missing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c2193c11ad215d3a2d7d35960630b3e1902a5082/activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb#L1456), there is a little magic here.

So in fact you should not be expecting the method options to be defined therefore getting nil for `baz`.

Comment: but in my case there is something there. so i don't understand why it's returning nil